# Linked lists - new record and edit record display of linked data

Tags: sharepoint-online

So this is likely one of those 'any fule knows how to do that' type questions, or one of those 'any fule knows you can't do that' type. Still, as the fule in question, guilty as charged (blush).
So let us say I have two lists, or rather, a list and a document library. The linkage allows multiple documents to be associated with a single line entry of Work_ID data:

DOCUMENT LIBRARY:
Document_Name, Document_Owner, Document_Contact, Work_ID - linked list field, displays LIST:Description, LIST:Work_Lead, LIST:Work_Contact

LIST:
Work_ID, Description, Work_Lead, Work_Contact

So far, all is well - at least for display purposes. The DOCUMENT record displays, along with related WORK_ID data. But when creating a new DOCUMENT entry, the Work_ID is a drop-down with, let's say, 200 potentially anonymous numbers in. Unless the person already knows the Work_ID to use, they would have to go away and find it. So what I'd like is for the drop down for Work_ID to also display the linked LIST:Description (and potentially other) fields in the (New Document metadata creation) screen that comes immediately after upload and when a DOCUMENT record is being edited. Of course, as the fule indicated above and a relative novice I have no idea if this can be done and if so how :-). Might anyone have any guidance/ comment?

Answer (score 0):

There is no OOB way to change the display format of the lookup column.

As a workaround, we could create a new column named "Test" to store value which concat Work_ID and Description column, then lookup it in document library.

Details on how to concat two columns in flow:

[image]

Concat format(Change the column internal name for yourself)：

```
concat(triggerBody()?['ExcelID'],triggerBody()?['ingt'])
```